# How to use extra data/sharedpref for more than one activity?

Tags: android

if i have 3 activities = **LoginActivity, Dashboard, Activity3**

**LoginActivity** send the extradata `OnClickListener`

```
Intent i = new Intent(loginActivity.this,Dashboard.class);
                    i.putExtra("student_id", StudentID);
                    startActivity(i);
```

then **Dashboard** retrieve it

```
Intent intent= getIntent();
String StdID = intent.getStringExtra("student_id");
```

the extra data works fine, but how can i reuse the extra data to **Activity3**?
the **Activity3** will start when i click `OnClickListener` from **Dashboard**

is it possible to reuse the extra data for more than 2 activities?
Please help me :)

Comment: Hmm. Preserve state of `Bundle` or `String StdID`  from Intent in Activity Dashboard like member of class and then pass it to Activity3.

Comment: `Preserve state of Bundle` i dont get it :( can u give me example?

Comment: Declare `String StdID` as class level member of `Dashboard` Activity and pass it in Intent to Activity3.

Comment: like this? `public final static String StdID="student_id";` how to pass it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean is it possible to pass off the data through multiple `Activities`, the answer is absolutely yes. You can easily do that by passing the data in a similar way to what you're doing now.

Let's say we're now in your Dashboard `Activity`, and want to open up `Activity` 3. If the Dashboard's calling `Intent` has any extras passed to it, you can pass them off like so:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Dashboard.this, Activity3.class);
if(getIntent().getExtras() != null) i.putExtras(getIntent().getExtras());
startActivity(i);
```

That's it. The key here is:

```
i.putExtras(getIntent().getExtras());
```

That is basically saying "put the `Bundle` the `Activity` was opened with into the `Bundle` of the `Intent` that will open the next `Activity`."

Keep in mind, any values added will overwrite pre-existing values set in the `Intent`, so ordering matters.

Comment: and i retrieve it in Activity3 with this also? `Intent intent= getIntent();
String StdID = intent.getStringExtra("student_id");`

Comment: Exactly! Since you're passing along the all the items with the same keys, you can retrieve them the same way you were before.

Comment: so I just need to repeat it any way? is there a way to get extra data without pass it from `OnClickListener`? i mean we use `OnClickListener` just once at the first activity.

Comment: If you want the data to be passed, you have to explicitly pass it. I'm not sure what you mean by passing data data from the OnClickListener?

Answer (score 0):

You'll either need to add this to the intent used to start Activity3 or a more common case is to save information like this to shared preferences (or a database) once you have successfully logged in.

Then you can lookup this data in each activity where needed (also you can use it to decide whether or not to show login screen when the user returns to the app) etc

//save user id
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString("user id", userId);
editor.commit();

//get userid
String userId = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("userid");

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the string from second activity to third activity using

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplication(), Activity3.class);
            intent1.putExtra("student_id",StdId);
            startActivity(intent1);
```

The first parameter in putExtra is a key, it could be any string. Intent is passed as a key-value pair. You could retrieve the value using the key in another activity.

While retrieving extra string in third activity i.e. Activity3

```
String studentId = getIntent().getStringExtra("student_id");
```

This will work fine.